How to make VS Code ignore a Go function
Is there anything in VS Code or Go that can help ignoring a function?
For instance, a function has some errors, but it's unused for the moment, but I need to test another functionality somewhere else in the project first, and I don't want to comment out the code.
Is there anything like this?
@ignoreThisFunction
func myFunc() {}


Why don't you want to comment out the code? I'm sure VS Code has a feature which makes that easy.

I know, its just that all that wall of green bother me sometimes, so I ask out of curiosity too.

Go provides the comment feature for ignoring code.   There is not a python-like @decorator for this purpose.

VSCode is an editor, it doesn’t care about your function. The toolchain however can’t compile code if there are errors.

I mean you could use build tags


Is there anything in VS Code or Go that can help ignoring a function?

No there isn’t.
